# Inclusion of form tag, submit button on click function is not called

Tags: javascript, backbone.js

I have a simple html form like this

```
<table>
    <tr><td >Topic: </td> <td>  <input type="text" name="Topic"></td></tr>
    <tr><td ><button id ="submit">submit</button></td></tr>
</table>
```

For this form i have implemented backbone.js, part of the code for backbone view is given below.

```
AppView = Backbone.View.extend({
    events: {
    "click #submit": "SubmitForm",
    },
    SubmitForm: function(){
    topic =     $("#Topic").val();
    var subject_model = new App_Form();
    subject_model.save();
    }
```

My question is, when i include the form tag in the html form above. On click of the 'submit' button the SubmitForm function is not called. Whereas on exclusion of the form tag the SubmitForm function is called on click of submit button.

Could somebody help with this please!

Comment: Please, update your html. I see no element with `id="submit"` and no `form` element.

Comment: My question is, if i include the form tag the SubmitForm function is not called.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should `return false;` in `SubmitForm` to prevent actual submitting.

```
var AppView = Backbone.View.extend({
    events: {
        "click #submit": "SubmitForm",
    },
    SubmitForm: function(){
        topic = $("#Topic").val();
        var subject_model = new App_Form();
        subject_model.save();
        return false;
    }
});
```

Comment: Seems dangerous, you should be doing `event.preventDefault()` instead of `return false`

Comment: @chemoish Why? Before you answer please take a look at [event.preventDefault() vs. return false](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1357118/event-preventdefault-vs-return-false). Just a tiny excerpt: "`return false` from within a jQuery event handler is effectively the same as calling both `e.preventDefault` and `e.stopPropagation` on the passed `jQuery.Event` object". `Backbone` is using `jQuery` for dispatching events.

Comment: @avrelian I know what it does. What is the point of e.stopPropagation() in this context (Return false can be dangerous if people don't understand what it does)? The problem that you are alluding to is that the form is actually submitting to a particular URL instead of executing the SubmitForm()... So you want to prevent the default behavior... A more thorough answer would be to update the event to a "submit" event instead (Preventing the firing of a click and a submit event), in addition to explicitly defining a type="submit" on the button... and helping the guy out to not define a global var.

Answer (score 0):

Check to make sure that you've defined an `el` in your `Backbone.View` and that the selector in your event map is with the scope of that `el`.

If the event isn't bound often times its because you've failed to provide a scoped selector.