# Pass object on form submit instead of field values

Tags: javascript, forms, backbone.js

I have a backbone.js application which saves input via the user into it's data model after passing validation. I have a standard submit button (no ajax) which submits to a page and that page by default uses what comes from the POST as forms do. How can I replace that data with the data from the backbone.js model? Is there a best practice to use in this situation?

Comment: Maybe you could write your validated model into a bunch of hidden fields, and read them after the POST on server side? But to be honest, why you wouldn't just use AJAX to post them as per answers below is a mystery....

Answer (score 0):

I would think that your best bet would be to utilize AJAX for the posting.  This will allow you to POST the data in whatever format your like as opposed to the query string format that HTML forms submit by default.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure about a best practice regarding the backbone.js framework model but I would suggest that you tap into the submit function of that form with Jquery.

```
   $('#formid').submit( function (event) {

       //enter code here

    });
```

Note that you can also include `event.preventDefault()` to prevent the automatic submission of the form, and instead implement your own entirely... Though doing all this is basically equivalent to including a regular button with an Ajax function inside.

Answer (score 0):

This post shows how to save it to your model: https://stackoverflow.com/a/8182418/222837
Like so:

```
var AppView = Backbone.View.extend({
  events: {
    "click #submit": "SubmitForm",
  },
  SubmitForm: function(){
    topic = $("#Topic").val();
    var subject_model = new App_Form();
    subject_model.save();
    return false;
  }
});
```